# Font Awesome, Webpack with url/file/-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome

This question has been answered in multiple questions before, but I'm afraid none of them work for me.

I'm using font-awesome from node_modules

all I wanna do is this

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
```

Here's my Webpack Code

```
webpackConfig.module.rules.push(
 {
   test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
   loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
 },
 {
   test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
   loader: "file-loader"
 }
)
```

The error, Please note I am getting the same error for all the different fonts in font-awesome

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
Module parse failed: /Users/valoster/Projects/app-ui/node_modules/url-loader/index.js?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff!/Users/valoster/Projects/app-ui/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 Unexpected token (1:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default = __webpack_public_path__ + "af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2";
@ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"minimize":true}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"plugins":[{"version":"5.2.17","plugins":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"postcssPlugin":"cssnano","postcssVersion":"5.2.17"}]}!./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 6:244-297
@ ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import a `.css` file, so you need to use `css-loader`.

Command Line:
`yarn add css-loader --dev`

In your webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
},
```